How to configure Google OAuth 2.0 to AVOID requesting user email address?
I'm using Google OAuth 2.0 for user authentication in my application, and it's working well. However, during the authentication/registration process, users are notified that my application will receive their email address. I don't need the user's email address for my application and would prefer not to request it at all.
Is there a way to configure Google OAuth 2.0 so that the user's email address is not requested or received? I want to ensure that users are not asked for permission to share their email address with my application. I understand that I can simply ignore and not persist the email address, but that's not the solution I'm looking for.
My Google search so far has been completely unsuccessful in this regard, and it seems to go against the design concept to not receive the email address. Nevertheless, I would like to ask this question because I genuinely do not want to know or handle my users' email addresses, especially from a privacy perspective.
Any guidance on how to adjust the OAuth 2.0 scopes or settings to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
    <div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id="<client id>"
        data-callback="handleGoogleCredentialResponse"
        data-prompt="select_account"
        data-scope="openid">
    </div>


please edit your question and include your code.   you should only see this if you ask for the email scope.  and possibly OpenID

Thank you Linda, that explains a lot.
I'm using
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="<client id>"
     data-callback="<my callback>"
     data-prompt="select_account">
</div>

But how to do it without OpenId which seems to be implicit by google.

Okay, it is not possible
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033268/oauth-2-0-scope-for-user-id-from-google-account?rq=2

OpenID is sign in.  It requires that you know the identity of the user the email identifies them.

Why do I need to know the email?
Google is sending the same ID so I know it is the same user.

To answer that question you should consult the rfc OpenID Connect Core 1.0  or Google open id connect  Or save yourself some time and just accept that its industry standard for open id connect to grant email scope.
